# Display an image even after the user has closed the app

Tags: android, dynamic, imageview, android-internal-storage

How do I load the same picture the user has selected even after the user closes the app?
I currently have the following code which I call in `onCreate`, but the `Bitmap` is null every time the user closes the app.

```
 private void loadImageFromStorage() {

        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File myPath = new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            File f = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath(), "profile.jpg");
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            ImageView coverView = findViewById(R.id.cover_view);
            coverView.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: If App is close where will you show the Image ? This does not make any sense .

Comment: Save the 'Image File-Path' in SharedPreferences and retrieve it next time (in onCreate) when the user opens the app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the image was actually saved as `profile.jpg` and it exists in the `imageDir` folder, all you need to do to load the image (based on your current usage) is:

```
private void loadImageFromStorage() {

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File myFile = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath(),"profile.jpg");

    if(myFile.exists()){
        try {
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFile.getAbsolutePath());
            ImageView coverView = findViewById(R.id.cover_view);
            coverView.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("MyApp", "The image file does not exist.");
    }

}
```

But if the image is not yet saved or non-existence, then you may need to ask another question that details how you are currently doing it. But this setup will allow you know if that image actually existts.